# PyInstaller + Asyncpg: Cannot import name exceptions

Tags: python, postgresql, pyinstaller, asyncpg, gino

I have a problem when I create a build with PyInstaller.

This is the stacktrace of error:

```
File "asyncpg/protocol/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 1, in init asyncpg.protocol.protocol
File "asyncpg/pgproto/./buffer.pyx", line 12, in init asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto
ImportError: cannot import name exceptions
```

I added the asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto when I compiled my application but the error persists.
This is an example of pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto --onefile --distpath  folter/example_service example/__main__.py --name example-app
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and I found this solution:

[just add more --hidden-import](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/596#issuecomment-747506434)

Python 3.9.4 Pyinstaller 4.2
It helps!